# javascript tool to test CSS3 attribute selectors only works in IE

Tags: javascript, css

I'm starting with CSS3 and am trying to write a tool for testing css attribute selectors. Below is the function I came up with, and the code I am running it against. 'cssInput' is just a textarea where the user enters their selector/rule.

It works fine in IE(!), but FF, Chrome and Safari just display the unstyled list. For example as 'cssInput' I enter:

```
a[rel^='friend'] {color:red;}
```

And IE correctly shows the first two list items in red, however, I can't get any other browser to display correctly. The IE dev tools show the above style statement correctly, but FF's DOM explorer displays 'Enter css here' instead. Is the selector/rule being cleaned out because of characters that need special encoding?

I'm using IE11, FF 28.0 (which I've read supports the CSS3 attr selectors), Chrome v33 and Safari 5.17 (is that most current? I can't finder newer update). Anyone have any ideas?

```
function showResults() {
  var cssQueryInput = document.getElementById("cssInput").innerHTML;
  var code = document.getElementById("codeExample").innerHTML;
  var resultsBox = document.getElementById("results");
  resultsBox.innerHTML = "<style>" + cssQueryInput + "</style><div>" + code + "</div>";
 }
```

And the code I am testing against:

```
<div id="codeExample">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#" lang="en-GB" rel="friend met">Peter</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" lang="es-ES" rel="friend">Pedro</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" lang="es-MX" rel="contact">Pancho</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Showed as red for me on chrome http://jsfiddle.net/rfdZS/

Comment: my Ubuntu Chrome shows it correct too

Comment: Displays correctly in Chrome 33. Please provide your versions of FF, Chrome and Safari.